# Поиск в двусвязном списке С++

Tags: c++, список

Поставлена задача сделай двусвязный список в котором методы класа добавляют/удаляют элемент списка, сортируют список, отображают элементы списка с начала/конца, поиск элемента в списке.
В приведенном ниже коде реализация сего, без поиска, не могу дойти до того как его реализовать.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <stack>

struct Node       //Структура являющаяся звеном списка
{
    int x;     //Значение x будет передаваться в список
    Node *Next, *Prev; //Указатели на адреса следующего и предыдущего элементов списка
};

class List
{
    Node *Head, *Tail, *cur;
    Node *Next, *Prev;//Указатели на адреса начала списка и его конца
public:
    List() :Head(NULL), Tail(NULL) {}; //Инициализируем адреса как пустые
    ~List();
    void Show();
    void Delete_end();
    void empty() { if (Head == NULL) cout << "Список пуст" << endl; else cout << "Список не пуст" << endl; }
    void Delete_first();
    void Add();
};

class iterator : public List
{
    friend Node;
public:
    iterator() {};
    iterator& operator++()
    {
        Node*temp;
        // Node=Node->Next;
        return *this;
    }
};

List::~List()
{
    while (Head) //Пока по адресу на начало списка что-то есть
    {
        Tail = Head->Next; //Резервная копия адреса следующего звена списка
        delete Head; //Очистка памяти от первого звена
        Head = Tail; //Смена адреса начала на адрес следующего элемента
    }
}

void List::Delete_first()
{

}

void List::Delete_end()
{
    Node *temp;
    Node *current = Tail;
    current = Head;
    temp = Head->Next;
    delete current;
    Head = temp;
    temp->Prev = NULL;
}

void List::Add()
{
    int x = 0;
    cout << "Введите элемент списка: ";
    cin >> x;
    Node *temp = new Node; //Выделение памяти под новый элемент структуры
    temp->Next = NULL;  //Указываем, что изначально по следующему адресу пусто
    temp->x = x;//Записываем значение в структуру

    if (Head != NULL) //Если список не пуст
    {
        temp->Prev = Tail; //Указываем адрес на предыдущий элемент в соотв. поле
        Tail->Next = temp; //Указываем адрес следующего за хвостом элемента
        Tail = temp; //Меняем адрес хвоста
    }
    else //Если список пустой
    {
        temp->Prev = NULL; //Предыдущий элемент указывает в пустоту
        Head = Tail = temp; //Голова=Хвост=тот элемент, что сейчас добавили
    }
}

void List::Show()
{

    //ВЫВОДИМ СПИСОК С КОНЦА
    Node *temp = Tail;
    //Временный указатель на адрес последнего элемента
    while (temp != NULL) //Пока не встретится пустое значение
    {
        cout << temp->x << " "; //Выводить значение на экран
        temp = temp->Prev; //Указываем, что нужен адрес предыдущего элемента
    }
    cout << "\n";

    //ВЫВОДИМ СПИСОК С НАЧАЛА
    temp = Head; //Временно указываем на адрес первого элемента
    while (temp != NULL) //Пока не встретим пустое значение
    {
        cout << temp->x << " "; //Выводим каждое считанное значение на экран
        temp = temp->Next; //Смена адреса на адрес следующего элемента
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    system("CLS");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    List lst;
    lst.empty();
    lst.Add();
    lst.empty();
    lst.Add();
    lst.Add();
    lst.empty();
    lst.Add();
    lst.Delete_first();
    lst.Delete_end();
    lst.Show();
    lst.Delete_end();
    lst.Add();
    lst.Delete_first();
    lst.Show();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Зачем у вас iterator наследуется от List? Зачем List содержит next/prev?

Comment: Ну, я с++ первый день учу, вот и не выходит недокод ))

Comment: Наследование здесь не нужно. Отнесите next/prev в iterator, к логике.

Comment: Поиск мало чем отличается от `Show`

Comment: Ох уж этот @Духсообщества, чувствствую себя некромантом)

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что структуру `Node` следует объявить как внутреннюю структуру класса `List`. Она не предназначена для использования за пределами класса `List`, а потому ее не следует делать открытой для внешнего мира.

Класс итератора также следует определить внутри класса списка. Он должен иметь доступ к начальному и конечному узлам списка.

Двусвязный список определяется своим головным и хвостовым узлами. Поэтому держать в определении списка данные переменные,  как `cur`, `Next` и `Prev` не имеет смысла. Вместо данных объявлений

```
Node *Head, *Tail, *cur;
Node *Next, *Prev;//Указатели на адреса начала списка и его конца
```

следует записать это объявление

```
Node *Head, *Tail;
```

Функция `empty` должна с помощью возвращаемого значения сообщать клиентскому коду, является ли список пустым или нет. Поэтому ее определение должно выглядеть следующим образом

```
bool empty() const
{ 
    return Head == nullptr;
}
```

Никакой вывод сообщений в эту функцию включаться не должен.

Фукнция `Delete_end` некорректная. Она должна удалять хвостовой узел, а вместо этого функция пытается удалить головной узел.

```
current = Head;
//...
delete current;
```

При этом если список до удаления узла содержал один элемент, то узел `Tail` после удаления этого единственного узла будет иметь не корректное значение вместо того, чтобы иметь значение `nullptr`

Функция может быть определена, например, следующим образом

```
void List::Delete_end()
{
    if ( Tail != nullptr )
    {
        Node *tmp = Tail;

        Tail = Tail->prev;

        delete tmp;

        if ( Tail == nullptr ) Head = Tail;
        else Tail->next = nullptr;    
    }
}
```

Так как у вас двусвязный список, то это означает, что новые элементы в список можно добавлять как в начало списка, так и в конец списка, а потому у вас должен быть объявлен не один метод `Add`, а два метода, один из которых добавляет новый элемент в начало списка, а другой - в конец списка.

И оба метода должны иметь один параметр, который задает целочисленное значение, которое нужно вставить в список. Вы не должны запрашивать это значение внутри самих методов.

Метод `Show` также должен быть разбит на два метода: один выводит список в прямом направлении, а другой метод - в обратном направлении.

Так что когда все это исправите, то можете спрашивать и про функцию поиска элемента в списке.:)

Comment: Пофиксил как и было написано вами выше, теперь после того как ввожу элементы, после ввода последнего программа вылетает с ошибкой " Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
temp was 0x1. "

Comment: @Jurtchak Возможно ваша функция ввода элементов не корректна. У меня была опечатка в функции удаления последнего элемента, Я ее подправил. Она должна устанавливать поле next в  nullptr.

Comment: Вместо "Tail" ?

Comment: @Jurtchak Я же написал, что я подправил функцию.

Comment: "Next" is undeclared identifier, хотя next ведь объявлен

Comment: @Jurtchak Next и next - это два разных идентификатора.

Comment: class "Node" has no member "prev" 
и аналогично с "next";
Мне выходит надо дополнительно в 
struct Node       
{
 int x;     
 Node *Next, *Prev; 
};
дописывать "next/prev" ?

Comment: @Jurtchak Используйте те идентификаторы, которые вы объявили.

Comment: Вот теперь и вопрос который писал выше, написал те которые объявлял я, и мне пишет " "Next" is undeclared identifier, хотя Next ведь объявлен ".

Comment: @Jurtchak Я все ясно в своем ответе написал, как удалить последний узел. Есть вопросы к моему ответ? А комментарии - это не место для переписки.

Comment: Тогда куда вам можно написал ?

Comment: @Jurtchak Мне не нужно писать. Закрывайте этот вопрос и задавайте новый на этом сайте с описанием той проблемы, которая у вас возникает.

Comment: Ну тогда вопрос этого топика, как организовать поиск ? :)

Comment: @Jurtchak Если все исправили, как я указал, то задавайте новый вопрос с указанием того, какие у вас возникают проблемы.

Comment: `Так как у вас двусвязный список, то это означает, что новые элементы в список можно добавлять как в начало списка, так и в конец списка` Так-то, тут можно добавлять элементы в любую позицию(Вы, вероятно, спутали с `deque`). Скорее нужно реализовать `addAfter/addBefore`

Answer (score 0):

Я провел некоторый рефакторинг и сделал желанный поиск элементов с использованием класса iterator. Но я его переименовал(этот класс) во избежание конфликта имен.

Вот готовая программа.

**Файл Main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include "List.h"
#include"iterat.h"

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    system("CLS");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    List lst;
    lst.Add();
    lst.Add();
    lst.Add();
    lst.Add();
    lst.Add();
    lst.Add();
    iterat it;
    cout << "====================================" << endl;
    for (it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << it << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    int key;
    cout << "Введите элемент поиска: "; cin >> key; cout << endl;
    for (it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it == key)
        {
            std::cout << "Элемент " << key << " найден.";
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    lst.Show();
    cout << endl;
    lst.Add();
    lst.Show();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**iterat.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>

class iterat : public List
{
public:
    Node* iter;
    iterat() {}
    iterat* operator=(Node*);
    iterat* operator++();
    bool operator!=(Node*);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const iterat&);
    bool operator==(int);
    bool operator==(Node*);
};
```

**iterat.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iterat.h"

iterat* iterat::operator=(Node *pv)
{
    iter = pv;
    return this;
}
iterat* iterat::operator++()
{
    iter = iter->Next;
    return this;
}
bool iterat::operator!=(Node * temp)
{
    if (this->iter != temp)
        return true;
   return false;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const iterat& it)
{
    os << it.iter->x;
     return os;
}
bool iterat::operator==(int key)
{
    if (iter->x == key)
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool iterat::operator==(Node *pv)
{
    if (iter == pv)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

**List.h**

```
#pragma once
class List
{
public:
    class Node {
    public:
        int x;
        Node *Next, *Prev;
        Node(int dat = 0) { x = dat; Next = 0; Prev = 0; }

    };
    Node *Head, *Tail;
    List() :Head(NULL), Tail(NULL) {};
    Node* begin() { return Head; }
    Node* end() { return Tail->Next; }
    void Show();
    void Delete_end();
    void Delete_first();
    void Add();

};
```

**List.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

void List::Add()
{
    int x = 0;
    cout << "Введите элемент списка: ";
    cin >> x;
    Node* pv = new Node(x);
    if (Head == 0)
    {
        Head = Tail = pv;
    }
    else
    {
        pv->Prev = Tail;
        Tail->Next = pv;
        Tail = pv;
    }
}

void List::Show()
{

    //ВЫВОДИМ СПИСОК С КОНЦА
    Node *temp = Tail;
    //Временный указатель на адрес последнего элемента
    while (temp != NULL) //Пока не встретится пустое значение
    {
       cout << temp->x << " "; //Выводить значение на экран
       temp = temp->Prev; //Указываем, что нужен адрес предыдущего элемента
    }
    cout << "\n";

    //ВЫВОДИМ СПИСОК С НАЧАЛА
    temp = Head; //Временно указываем на адрес первого элемента
    while (temp != NULL) //Пока не встретим пустое значение
    {
        cout << temp->x << " "; //Выводим каждое считанное значение на экран
        temp = temp->Next; //Смена адреса на адрес следующего элемента
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```